# Why am I getting undefined method with partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

It had just worked, but when I exited out of a bunch of files it stopped working so I need some fresh eyes to see what I need to put back or take out.

```html
app/views/goals/_upcoming.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_goals__upcoming_html_erb__311311984007827814_70285435296160'
app/views/sidebar/_sidebar.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_sidebar__sidebar_html_erb__935147241238506257_70285436475880'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__784590708649109669_70285432904920'
```

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Line #2   <% @top_3_goals.each do |goal| %>
```

**layouts/application.html.erb**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Personal Control Center</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  <!-- Tells app to be mobile responsive -->
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
    <% end %>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= render 'sidebar/sidebar' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**sidebar/_sidebar.html.erb**

```html
<div class="sidebar">
<div id="sidebarsectiontop" class="panel panel-default">
<div id="sidebarheadingtop" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Today</b></h5></div>
  <%= render 'habits/today' %>
</div>
<div id="sidebarsection" class="panel panel-default">
<div id="sidebarheading" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Upcoming</b></h5></div>
  <%= render 'goals/upcoming' %>
</div>
<div id="sidebarsection" class="panel panel-default">
<div id="sidebarheading" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Count</b></h5></div>
  <%= render 'sidebar/count' %>
 </div>
<div id="sidebarsection" class="panel panel-default">
<div id="sidebarheading" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Tags</b></h5></div>
 <div id="tag_cloud">
  <%= render 'sidebar/tags' %> 
 </div>
</div>
<div id="sidebarsection" class="panel panel-default">
<div id="sidebarheading" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Recommendations</b></h5></div>
  <%= render 'sidebar/recommendations' %>
</div>
<div id="sidebarsectionbottom" class="panel panel-default">
<div id="sidebarheading" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Memorize</b></h5></div>
  <%= render 'sidebar/memorize' %>
</div>
</div>
```

**goals/upcoming.html.erb**

```html
<table>
  <% @top_3_goals.each do |goal| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong>
          <%= link_to top_3_goal.name, edit_goal_path(top_3_goal) %>
        </strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= top_3_goals.deadline.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**goals controller**

```html
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @goals = Goal.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @goals = Goal.all.order("deadline")
      @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished
      @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
      @top_3_goals = @unaccomplished_goals.top_3
    end
  end
```

**goal model**

```html
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 acts_as_taggable
 scope :accomplished, -> { where(accomplished: true) }
 scope :unaccomplished, -> { where(accomplished: false) }
 validates :name, presence: true

 # class for sidebar
 scope :top_3, -> do
   order("deadline DESC").
   limit(3)
 end
end
```

**sidebar controller**

```html
class SidebarController < ApplicationController

  def sidebar
    @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
    @top_3_goals = @unaccomplished_goals.top_3
  end
end
```

Thanks I reset the database to see if that would work but it didn't :/

I'm new to trying to incorporate a few different controllers in the sidebar so I'm still learning as I go. Here's the fulltrace:

```html
app/views/goals/_upcoming.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_goals__upcoming_html_erb__311311984007827814_70285435296160'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
haml (4.0.6) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_with_haml'
app/views/sidebar/_sidebar.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_sidebar__sidebar_html_erb__935147241238506257_70285436475880'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
haml (4.0.6) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_with_haml'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__784590708649109669_70285432904920'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@top_3_goals` is nil. Double-check that this chain of assignments returns what you think they should, based on what's in the database:

```
 @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished
 @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
 @top_3_goals = @unaccomplished_goals.top_3
```

Comment: Agreed. In my experience, associated model objects can return `nil` if no associations are found.

Comment: Since I reset the database are you saying it's `nil` because their is nothing in it now? Do you know how I fix it? Thanks so much for your timely response! I tried this: `render "no_goals" if @unaccomplished_goals.top_3.nil?`

Comment: I just removed `@top_3_goals = @unaccomplished_goals.top_3` and all the logic associated with it and put in the regular goals index code into _upcoming and yet I still get the error so I don't think `@top_3_goals` is the problem.

Comment: Try @top_3_goals = Goal.all just to isolate. Based on the stack trace it seems like there's only one reason like the answer suggested. Else if you feel uneasy maybe you can just restart your server to isolate weird issues. Should be the assignment though

Comment: I got it to work if I deleted the _sidebar info and then added a goal via the form and then copy & pasted the info back into where it will then show in the _sidebar since its not nil anymore, but if I try to edit it I get the error again. What's the deal here? And what code do I need to prevent the nil error if their is no goals submitted yet? Thanks @Mingsheng for the suggestion.

Comment: Wow sorry, that's confusing. Lol. As in I got load by the _sidebar things... sorry. But I must agree with the answer. It should be somewhere along the "def sidebar" code in your controller. I'm not sure what's the best practice for handling the exception, but I would just do a check in the view layer. Basically an if statement to check if the variable is nil. Maybe someone else can provide a better recommendation

Comment: @Mingsheng this makes no sense! I tried "if" and I'm still getting the error with no clue what to do at this point. Thanks for trying tho.

Comment: Did u check whether goals is nil? As in in your controller. I'm not sure which of the variable is nil. But it's definitely one of them. Can't help you on tracing that though.  Haha

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this to fix the nill problem:

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_top_3_goals

  def set_top_3_goals
    @top_3_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.top_3
  end
end
```

which I got from here: [How to stop NoMethodError when clicking #new & #edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787449/how-to-stop-nomethoderror-when-clicking-new-edit/28787711#28787711)