# How to stop NoMethodError when clicking #new & #edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, sidebar, nomethoderror

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to incorporate multiple controller's logic into a sidebar.

For example, I want to have a section in the sidebar that uses `@habits` logic from the habits_controller and a section that uses `@unaccomplished_goals` logic from the goals_controller.

For this question let's just focus on `@unaccomplished_goals`.

`<% @top_3_goals.each do |goal| %>` shows correctly in the app's sidebar, which is derived from the goals_controller #index `@top_3_goals = @unaccomplished_goals.top_3` **BUT** if I click on links [goals/new](http://goals/new) or [goals/1/edit](http://goals/1/edit) I get the dreaded: `undefined method each for nil:NilClass`!

Here's a view breakdown:

I use `<%= render 'sidebar/sidebar' %>` in `views/layouts/application.html.erb`
to grab `views/sidebar/_sidebar.html.erb` in order to use `<%= render 'goals/upcoming' %>` to grab `views/goals/_upcoming.html.erb`

**views/goals/_upcoming.html.erb**

```html
<table>
  <% @top_3_goals.each do |goal| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong>
          <%= link_to goal.name, edit_goal_path(goal) %>
        </strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= goal.deadline.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**views/sidebar/_sidebar.html.erb**

```html
<div id="sidebarsection" class="panel panel-default">
<div id="sidebarheading" class="panel-heading"><h5><b>Upcoming</b></h5></div>
  <%= render 'goals/upcoming' %>
</div>
```

**goals controller**

```html
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @goals = Goal.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @goals = Goal.all.order("deadline")
      @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished
      @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
      @top_3_goals = @unaccomplished_goals.top_3
    end
  end
```

**goal model**

```html
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 acts_as_taggable
 scope :accomplished, -> { where(accomplished: true) }
 scope :unaccomplished, -> { where(accomplished: false) }
 validates :name, presence: true

 scope :top_3, -> do
  order("deadline DESC").
  limit(3)
end
end
```

Do I need to put anything in the sidebar_controller? I played around with adding logic there but it didn't seem to make any difference. I'm still a beginner so what I'm saying here may make no sense. Right now I have nothing in the sidebar_controller since the only view I have from there is `_sidebar.html.erb` (I'm not quite sure how partials utilize controllers). The partial `_upcoming.html.erb` worked perfectly if I rendered it in the goals index (the links all worked), but how can I get it to work if I render it in the _sidebar?

**Thanks for putting up with me this far =]**

Comment: If the sidebar is present on all pages, then you either need to add code to every request (via the application controller) that populates all the `@` variables used by the sidebar views or the sidebar views need to make separate requests to the server via ajax. Only one controller is active on each request.

Comment: I think part of the issue might be some confusion around controller methods (or "actions"). A request, let's say a GET to `goals/new`, will be parsed by the Routing engine and directed to one controller action. All the code necessary to be displayed for that view must be included in that one action. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be such a thing as a sidebar controller, unless you plan to make the sidebar some sort of iframe or something ( which is strange ).

Like @patrickmcgraw suggested, I would create a before_action in the application controller to make sure that those variables are always set.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_top_3_goals

  def set_top_3_goals
    @top_3_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.top_3
  end
end
```